# Decrypting return of function in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'am  trying to  decrypt the return of calc function below but i'am very confused. 
I have the f function that takes 3 ints and returns an int. 
The calc fuction i think should return `val calc : int -> int = <fun>` because f has to take 3 ints, i'am giving it x and y so now it needs one more to return another int, the final result. Why it this logic not correct?
I can't make any sense of the actual output, specially with the polymorfic values when i forced parameters in f to be integers.

```
# let f (x : int) (y : int) (z : int) = x + y + z;;
val f : int -> int -> int -> int = <fun>
# let calc x y f = f x y;;
val calc : 'a -> 'b -> ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'c = <fun>
```

Comment: What about this equivalent code`let f (x : int) (y : int) (z : int) = x + y + z    let calc x y g = g x y`? The argument f (here g) in the definition of calc creates a new binding that shadows the f declared before. They have nothing in common.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression `let calc x y f = f x y;;`, `f` is a locally-bound variable (`calc` binds `x`, `y` and then `f`) rather than the function you have defined before.

If you had written `let calc x y = f x y;;` then you'd have the expected result.

Comment: Now that makes sense, thanks. Let me just see if i get the logic of calc right. It takes some a, some b and some function that takes the previous a and b to output something, 'c which in turn is the return of calc. Is this right?

Comment: That's indeed exactly what it does. :)

Answer (score 1):

The function `calc` contains no reference to the function`f`. There is an argument named `f` be it could be named `g` without changing anything: `let calc x y g = g x y`. If you want to use the function `f` you have defined above and not any function of the right type, you must not pass `f` as an argument, you should rewrite `calc` like this:

```
let f x y z = x + y + z
let calc x y = f x y
```

and then `calc` will have the type `int -> int -> (int -> int)` which is more commonly written as `int -> int -> int -> int`.